# Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am fetching images from an endpoint and having trouble pushing each mapped file into my local array. I am receiving the error `Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'`.

- I tried setting all arguments to `blob` to no success.
- Tried setting `function(data)` to `data: any`, `data: {}`, `data: File[]`, `data: JSON` and all say map functionality does not work on these types.
- I think the problem may be within my state.mediaLibrary. Perhaps that is where I need to assign the array type?

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Company } from "data/companies"
import { Asset } from "data/companies"

interface MediaLibraryProps {
  company: Company
}

class MediaLibrary extends React.Component<MediaLibraryProps> {
  state = {
    mediaLibrary: []
  }

  getMediaLibrary = async () => {
    await fetch(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_SA_API_URL}/${this.props.company.id}/medialibrary`,
    ).then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(function (data) {
        return data.map((file: Asset) => {
          return {
            id: file.assetId,
            path: file.path
          }
        })
      }).then(data => this.state.mediaLibrary.push(...data))
  }

  public render() {
    const files = this.state.mediaLibrary.map((file: Asset) => (
      <div key={file.assetId}>
        <div>
          <img src={`url(${process.env.REACT_APP_SA_CDN_URL}${file.path})`} />
        </div>
      </div>
    ))

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>Media Library</h2>
          {files}
          <button onClick={this.getMediaLibrary}>Get Files</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MediaLibrary
```

- Expect the state array to be populated with many image files.
- Actual results are TypeScript is complaining.

IMPORTANT: After solving this issue I found my problem was not with the state. Although the solution allows me to push objects into the array I was mutating the state directly which is a nono in React. See below:

```
class MediaLibrary extends React.Component<MediaLibraryProps> {
  state = {
    mediaLibrary: []
  }

  getMediaLibrary = async () => {
    await fetch(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_SA_API_URL}/${this.props.company.id}/medialibrary`
      }
    ).then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(function (data: any) {
        return data.map((file: Asset) => Object.assign(file, {
          assetId: file.assetId,
          path: file.path
        }))
      }).then((data) => this.setState({ mediaLibrary: [...data] }))
  }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should declarate your `mediaLibrary` array like this:

```
state = {
  mediaLibrary: Array<{id: string, path: string}>()
}
```

or like this:

```
state: {
  mediaLibrary: {id: string, path: string}[]
} = {
  mediaLibrary: []
}
```

With the first way you're telling TypeScript you want to put objects with the given attributes inside the `mediaLibrary` array. With just `[]` TypeScript will put the `never` type to the array and hence fails to put anything into it.

The second example describes the complete `state` object and not just the included array.

Comment: I understand that although now I'm given `'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)` Can't I define types in the state?

Comment: I think it has to be written something like this `mediaLibrary: [] = Array[]`

Comment: See my updated answer. You're partly right and I were partly wrong.