# reactjs + typescript getting error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to setState with componentDidMount after axios request is fulfilled, I am getting error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Below is the code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import axios from 'axios';

import {
  updateFilterByCategory,
  UpdateFilterRequest,
} from 'ducks/search/filters/reducer';

import { GlobalState } from 'ducks/rootReducer';
import { APPLY_BTN_TEXT } from '../constants';

interface OwnProps {
  categoryId: string;
}

interface StateFromProps {
  value: string;
}

interface DispatchFromProps {
  updateFilter: (
    categoryId: string,
    value: string | undefined,
  ) => UpdateFilterRequest;
}

export type InputFilterProps = StateFromProps & DispatchFromProps & OwnProps;

export interface InputFilterState {
  value: string;
  dropDownValue: {};
}

export class InputFilter extends React.Component<
  InputFilterProps,
  InputFilterState
> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: props.value,
      dropDownValue: {dept: [],
      items: [],
      emp: [],
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = (prevProps: StateFromProps) => {
    axios.get("/api/data")
      .then(response=>{
        Object.keys(response["result"]).map((key, value)=>{
          
          this.setState(prevState => {
            let dropDownValue = {...prevState.dropDownValue};
            dropDownValue[key] = value
            return {dropDownValue}
          })
        })
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
  };

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps: StateFromProps) => {
    const newValue = this.props.value;
    if (prevProps.value !== newValue) {
      this.setState({ value: newValue || '' });
    }
  };

  onApplyChanges = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.value) {
      this.props.updateFilter(this.props.categoryId, this.state.value);
    } else {
      this.props.updateFilter(this.props.categoryId, undefined);
    }
  };

  onInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {

    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };
  
  render = () => {
    const { categoryId } = this.props;
    return (
      <form
        className="input-section-content form-group"
        onSubmit={this.onApplyChanges}
      >

             <input
             list={categoryId}
             className="form-control dropdown-input"
             name={categoryId}
             id={categoryId}
             onChange={this.onInputChange}
             value={this.state.value}
           />
        <button name={categoryId} className="btn btn-default" type="submit">
          {APPLY_BTN_TEXT}
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  };
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state: GlobalState, ownProps: OwnProps) => {
  const filterState = state.search.filters;
  const value = filterState[state.search.resource]
    ? filterState[state.search.resource][ownProps.categoryId]
    : '';
  return {
    value: value || '',
  };
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      updateFilter: (categoryId: string, value: string | undefined) =>
        updateFilterByCategory({ categoryId, value }),
    },
    dispatch
  );

export default connect<StateFromProps, DispatchFromProps, OwnProps>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(InputFilter);
```

error log

```
#23 59.03 ERROR in /app/static/js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/FilterSection/index.tsx
#23 59.03 ./js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/FilterSection/index.tsx
#23 59.03 [tsl] ERROR in /app/static/js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/FilterSection/index.tsx(48,15)
#23 59.03       TS2322: Type '{ categoryId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Omit<never, "value" | "updateFilter"> & OwnProps>'.
#23 59.03   Property 'categoryId' is incompatible with index signature.
#23 59.03     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
#23 59.03  @ ./js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/index.tsx 5:0-44 15:40-53
#23 59.03  @ ./js/pages/SearchPage/index.tsx 11:0-42 88:36-48
#23 59.03  @ ./js/index.tsx 21:0-44 48:69-79
#23 59.03 
#23 59.03 ERROR in /app/static/js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/InputFilter/index.spec.tsx
#23 59.03 [tsl] ERROR in /app/static/js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/InputFilter/index.spec.tsx(31,43)
#23 59.03       TS2786: 'InputFilter' cannot be used as a JSX component.
#23 59.03   Its instance type 'InputFilter' is not a valid JSX element.
#23 59.03     Types of property 'componentDidMount' are incompatible.
#23 59.03       Type '(prevProps: StateFromProps) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
#23 59.03 
#23 59.03 ERROR in /app/static/js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/InputFilter/index.tsx
#23 59.03 ./js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/InputFilter/index.tsx
#23 59.03 [tsl] ERROR in /app/static/js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/InputFilter/index.tsx(54,3)
#23 59.03       TS2416: Property 'componentDidMount' in type 'InputFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Component<InputFilterProps, InputFilterState, any>'.
#23 59.03   Type '(prevProps: StateFromProps) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
#23 59.03  @ ./js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/FilterSection/index.tsx 9:0-41 19:43-54
#23 59.03  @ ./js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/index.tsx 5:0-44 15:40-53
#23 59.03  @ ./js/pages/SearchPage/index.tsx 11:0-42 88:36-48
#23 59.03  @ ./js/index.tsx 21:0-44 48:69-79
#23 59.03 
#23 59.03 ERROR in /app/static/js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/InputFilter/index.tsx
#23 59.03 ./js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/InputFilter/index.tsx
#23 59.03 [tsl] ERROR in /app/static/js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/InputFilter/index.tsx(138,3)
#23 59.03       TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof InputFilter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'.
#23 59.03   Type 'typeof InputFilter' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<never, any>'.
#23 59.03     Construct signature return types 'InputFilter' and 'Component<never, any, any>' are incompatible.
#23 59.03       The types of 'props' are incompatible between these types.
#23 59.03         Type 'Readonly<InputFilterProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to type 'never'.
#23 59.03  @ ./js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/FilterSection/index.tsx 9:0-41 19:43-54
#23 59.03  @ ./js/pages/SearchPage/SearchFilter/index.tsx 5:0-44 15:40-53
#23 59.03  @ ./js/pages/SearchPage/index.tsx 11:0-42 88:36-48
#23 59.03  @ ./js/index.tsx 21:0-44 48:69-79
#23 59.03 
#23 59.03 webpack 5.6.0 compiled with 4 errors in 53077 ms
#23 59.38 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#23 59.38 npm ERR! errno 2
#23 59.38 npm ERR! static@1.0.0 build: `cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT='tsconfig.webpack.json' webpack --progress --config webpack.prod.ts`
#23 59.38 npm ERR! Exit status 2
#23 59.38 npm ERR! 
#23 59.38 npm ERR! Failed at the static@1.0.0 build script.
#23 59.38 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#23 59.39 
#23 59.39 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#23 59.39 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-07-13T07_55_35_192Z-debug.log
```

Tried looking for answers in [Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55952200/argument-of-type-any-is-not-assignable-to-type-never)

Since I am new to react and typescript, couldn't solve it, despite looking for answers in internet.

I observed that if I remove componentDidMount, it builds fine without error. and if i remove `prevProps: StateFromProps` from `componentDidMount = (prevProps: StateFromProps)`and just keep `componentDidMount = ()` then it works fine as well.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide reproducable example

Comment: Btw, here `dropDownValue[key] = value` you have a state mutation, maybe it is a problem

Comment: @captain-yossarian if i remove all the code from .then() section and only keep console.log("success") still problem persists. i have checked that. `dropDownValue[key] = value` is not a problem right now.

Comment: please share your code in any sandbox, otherwise it will be hard for you to gen a proper answer

Comment: @captain-yossarian i dont know how to do that, since i am new to it. can you suggest, how to?

Comment: check this site https://codesandbox.io/s/new
You should reproduce all files (relative to your problem) in this sandbox and make sure you are receiving same error.

Also, you can share your git repo

Comment: @captain-yossarian i tried setting it on link you provided but got stuck. could you please let me know what can be the issue by looking the given code and error log in question? and also if i remove prevProps: StateFromProps from componentDidMount = (prevProps: StateFromProps)and just keep componentDidMount = () then it works fine as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234823/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-young-minds1).

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of issues in your code regardless of your question.

One of them is using `axios` response incorrectly.

```js
axios.get("/api/data")
      .then(response=>{
        Object.keys(response["result"]).map((key, value)=>{
```

It seems that you're trying to access `result` from the request `body`.
In order to do so, you should access it through `response.data.result`;

Other than that, the source of the presented problem is coming from the fact that you declared your state `interface` incorrectly.

```js
export interface InputFilterState {
  value: string;
  dropDownValue: {};
}
```

Asserting `{}` type for `dropDownValue` means that this key can only contain EMPTY OBJECT (`never`).
You are trying to access some property in `dropDownValue` using a `string` based key (`dropDownValue[key]`).
Therefore, TypeScript complains that you can not retrieve a value with a string key from an object which declared as an empty object.

In order to declare it accordingly, You can declare the right type of `dropDownValue` in your interface.

```js
export interface InputFilterState {
  value: string;
  dropDownValue: {
      value: props.value,
      dropDownValue: {
        dept: [],
        items: [],
        emp: [],
      }
    };
}
```