# Suggestions Complete Typescript & React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
    if (value.length > 0) {
      const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, "i");
      suggestions = data.sort().filter((v: IData) => regex.test(v.name));
    }
    setIsComponentVisible(true);
    setSearch({ suggestions, text: value });  
  };
```

when I use it it gives me an error in this line in "suggestions" :
`setSearch({ suggestions, text: value });`

The error is:
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.

How can I solve this, I'm trying to autocomplete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55952200/argument-of-type-any-is-not-assignable-to-type-never)

Comment: Your piece of code is not enough to well understand what happens in your code

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont have a type or have an array type on your useState

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).